# Adding to end of Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list

I am currently studying up on linked lists in Java. I have a sample program that works as expected for certain input, and not at all for other input.

```
//Constructor in class List of People
ListOfPeople() {
    Person listHead = new Person("LIST HEAD");
    personList = listHead;
    lastPerson = listHead;
    numberPeople = 0;
}
//Adds person to the beginning of the list
public void addFirst(Person newP) {
    newP.next = personList.next;
    personList.next = newP;
    numberPeople++;
}
//Adds person to the end of the list
public void addLast(Person lastP) {
    lastPerson.next = lastP;
    lastPerson = lastP;
    numberPeople++;
}
```

For the Person class, I have the following code:

```
//From the Person class
String name;
Person next;

Person(String n) {
    name = n;
    next = null;
}
```

Suppose I add two different people to the beginning of the list:

```
Person mulan = new Person("Mulan");
myFriends.addFirst(mulan);
Person mushu = new Person("Mushu");
myFriends.addFirst(mushu);
```

Then, the code works without problems. And I get the output: "Mushu, Mulan". 
**HOWEVER**, if I add one person at the beginning of the list, and another at the end, I get a NullPointerException. If I try to invoke the addLast(String name) method on both Person objects, there seems to be no problem.

Any tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm missing the fields of your `ListOfPeople` class and the exact point where the NPE is thrown. NPEs at this level can be easily spotted runnning a debugger, you should try to use it. That said, think about what should happen to `lastPerson` if you add a `Person` with `addFirst` to an **empty** list...

Comment: `... And I get the output: "Mushu, Mulan".` please show how do you fetch this names

Comment: I have written a method in the Person class: "public void write() { System.out.println(name); }.
As well as another method in the ListOfPeople class: "public void writeAll() { Person p = personlist.next; for(int i = numberPeople; i>0; i--) {p.write(); p = p.next; }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 // I left out getters and setters for brevity.
 class PersonNode {
      Person current;
      PersonNode next;
      PersonNode previous;
 }

 class PersonList {
       PersonNode head; 
       PersonNode tail;

      public PersonList(){ 
          head.previous = null;
          tail.next = null;
      }
      void addFront(Person p){ 
          if (head.person == null) {
                head.person = p; 
          }
          else {
               PersonNode temp = head; head= new PersonNode(p);               
               temp.previous = head; head.next = temp;
               }
          }
     void addBack(Person p) {
          if (tail.person == null) {
                tail.person = p; 
          }
          else {
              PersonNode temp = tail;
              tail= new PersonNode(p);               
              temp.next = tail;
              tail.previous = temp;
      }

     int count() {
          int c = 0;
          for(PersonNode n = head; head.next != null; n = head.next){
              if (n.Person !=null){
                  ++c;
              }
          }
          return c;
     }
}
```